# call list of products into a block in magento

Tags: html, magento, product

I created a static block into my main page which is empty right now. What i want to do is load some products into it (with visible picture and product description).
Currently i have this content in my static block:

```
<div class="plist">
<div class="plist-title">
<p><strong>Rollen/R&auml;der - Aktionen</strong></p>
</div>
<div class="block-content">
<ul>
<li>Product 1</li>
<li>Product 2</li>
<li>Product 3</li>
<li>Product 4</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

instead of the "Product X" as a text, I want to have picture with description, as mentioned above. how can i do that? is there a tool for it or can i do it myself?

thanks

Comment: Are you creating the static block from the admin panel or are you creating it from phtml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [here](http://www.mcnab.co/blog/e-commerce/magento/magento-displaying-products-in-a-static-block/) is the brief description about adding the product in the static block.

As you can see it uses the category id to display the product from that particular category.

If you want to display the products you like than you have to get the products by loading their entity id or sku to the product model like below example in your template file.

> Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($entity_id);

Hope this will help.

Comment: Lol, that's put a smile on my face :).  Feel free to copy any of the code into the actual answer - not that I am planning on deleting my blog any time soon but it's seen as good practice here as it stops link rot ruining good answers.

Comment: wow it worked!! thank you! it just looks ugly right now because the products don't fit into the column. how can i fix that?

Comment: i just added 2 for testing

Comment: You have used this template "catalog/product/list.phtml" go to this file and you can make your amendments here.But this changes will effect other product listing design as by default magento use this template to display product list.

Comment: but i could create my own list.phtml file and just change this part "catalog/product/list.phtml" to my own

Comment: If you want you own template file than give it any other name and change that name in the static block too.and you can do whatever you like in that file.it only affect that static block.

Answer (score 0):

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" category_id="100" column_count="4" template="catalog/product/custom_list.phtml"}}
```

This will call a block similar to what you see on category pages, it will show products from category with **id=100**